# Blank Plot coming up

Tags: r

So I downloaded latest version of `R` from cran.r-project R 3.4.2

I also followed instructions to download XQuartz and tools needed.

Then I tried one of the demos `demo(lm.glm)` got what looked right for this type of analysis

but plank pop up just titled Quartz 2[ * ]
pops ups. Completely blank.
Then after analysis there is `"Hit <Return> to see next plot:"`
So I hit return and get the same blank popup titled "Quartz 2[*]"
and next line says

```
Error in plot.new() : attempt to plot on null device
```

I searched for this error code online but google gives just three results, person with different data but same issue. They did not get response

as asked in comment

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8/C/en_IE.UTF-8/en_IE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2
```

Comment: (1) What do the first 44 lines of your code have to do with anything? Please exert more effort on *minimal relevant code* to support your question. (2) I can execute your code and see the plot without error, this is unreproducible. Have you restarted your R session (and/or RStudio, if you are using it) and see if it works? If that does not work, I suggest you include in your question the output from `sessionInfo()` (after you've restarted R and run just the last 8 lines of this code).

Comment: I thought I should show that this ran fine. I tried reinstalling r, same issue.

Comment: Please learn to format code within questions, it makes it much easier when the formatting is consistent; I've suggested an edit that makes it easier to read. I don't have a mac so I cannot test this, sorry. Hopefully somebody else has already seen this issue, because without any reproducible code it'll be difficult to get help.